# How to copy rows x times based on cell values into another sheet, & create a new column filled with specific content?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA and I'm struggling with something I can't manage to succeed.

I have several columns, some of which work in pairs : the first element of the pair represents a size, and the second a corresponding quantity.
My goal is to copy into a new sheet as many entire rows as there are in each corresponding quantity, minus the other quantity & size columns - knowing that the value of the "size" columns is not always identical for a given column.

I would like to be able to report the current size onto a specific column on the target sheet (see example below)

As a picture often speaks better than words, I would like it to work as follows:

[image: Excel VBA schema]

Here is my code attempt, but it only copies one row at a time (which isn't the most problematic, I can handle to repeat it multiple times), but it doesn't report the size to a unique column in the target sheet:

```
Public Sub CopyData()
Dim rngSinglecell As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
Dim intCount As Integer

Set rngQuantityCells = Range("C2", Range("C2").End(xlDown))

For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
    If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then
        If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
            For intCount = 1 To rngSinglecell.Value
                Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Feuil2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

I hope my explanation is clear enough.
(and sorry for my possible bad English, which isn't my mother language!)

Comment: Please show us your code attemps :)

Comment: Code attempt added :)

Comment: Ok, I managed to selectively copy cells, by replacing
```
Range(rngSinglecell.Address).EntireRow.Copy
```
by
```
Range("A" & rngSinglecell.Row & ":B" & rngSinglecell.Row).Copy
```
But it only select consecutive cells withn a range, while I would like to copy a non consecutive cell selection. Any ideas ?

Comment: This is how you can copy/paste non-contiguous ranges of cells.  https://excelribbon.tips.net/T005228_Copying_and_Pasting_Non-Contiguous_Ranges_of_Cells.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try that:

```
Public Sub CopyData()
Dim rngSinglecell As Range
Dim rngQuantityCells As Range
Dim intCount As Integer
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim name_ws As String
Dim lastRow As Long, lastRow2 As Long

name_ws = "Sheet1" '<--- put name of your main worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(name_ws)
With ws1

    lastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngQuantityCells = .Range("C2:C" & lastRow)

    For Each rngSinglecell In rngQuantityCells
        If IsNumeric(rngSinglecell.Value) Then

            If rngSinglecell.Value > 0 Then
                For intCount = 1 To rngSinglecell.Value
                    lastRow2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil2").Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                    .Rows(rngSinglecell.Row).EntireRow.Copy ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Feuil2").Rows(lastRow2)
                Next
            End If

        End If
    Next

End With

End Sub
```